# Disable long 'double free or corruption' messages

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I am using a third-party `C++` app, which owing to some bug occasionally spews out a double free or corruption error. The error does not prevent the app from functioning normally and I do not have desire to debug third-party apps. Therefore, I just lived with the occasional messages. However, after updating `Ubuntu` from `14.04` to `16.04` the one-line error messages became pages of annoying text in my terminal, like:

```
*** Error in `/usr/bin/~': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x000055eebccb43d0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f78579047e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7fe0a)[0x7f785790ce0a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f785791098c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib~.so.6(Nlm_MemFree+0xe)[0x7f7857e9381e]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib~.so.6(ReleaseAppErrInfo+0xb3)[0x7f7857e8e4b3]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib~.so.6(Nlm_ReleaseAppContext+0x56)[0x7f7857e91ae6]
/usr/bin/~(NlmThreadExit+0x73)[0x55eebb7d1513]
/usr/bin/~(+0x85d7)[0x55eebb7d15d7]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76ba)[0x7f7857c5d6ba]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f785799382d]
======= Memory map: ========
55eebb7c9000-55eebb7d4000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4334530                    /usr/bin/~
~
~
```

My question: is there a way to disable backtrace and limit the message to just the first line under `Ubuntu 16.04`?

Comment: There's a bug in the program. Quite a serious one it seems. One that you should tell the *author* of the program about.

Comment: The bug is already registered at the page of the vendor

Comment: No, actually it does not. This error message is technically not  a part of the program output (but comes from the OS directly instead) and therefore cannot be just redirected to `/dev/null`